# How to integrate MySQL with .NET Core 3 and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I have a database project on full `.NET Framework` with `Entity framework 6.3` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` as provider (package `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.EntityFramework bot 8.0.18`). This all works as expected.

Now I would like to port this to `.NET Core 3.0`.I still need to stay on `Entity framework 6.3` and use old `EDMX model`.I've created new Core project and linked database entities and `edmx` ([port existing EF 6.3 to core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/)). The problem I  encounter is that the provider `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` (`MySql.Data.EntityFramework` NuGet package) doesn't seem to include a `.NET Core` version.

Am I missing a NuGet package? Do I need another MySql provider, that will work on `.NET Core 3.0` and `Entity Framework 6.3`?

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile, Oracle ports their code to .NET Core 3.0, we released our package that supports it:

- Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.MySql.Data.Entity/
- GitHub: https://github.com/zzzprojects/mysql-connector-net

Comment: Does it support EF Core 3.x now?

Comment: No Mukus, it doesn't seem to support it so you can continue to use our package.

Answer (score 2):

You will need MySql.Data.EntityFramework to port their provider to support .NET Core 3.0 (and possibly EF 6.3) before you can proceed.